# Linq query for selecting an item from tree structure, but to look in the whole depth

Tags: c#, linq

Here's a class I made:

```
public class ItemTree
{

    public Int32 id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public String text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<ItemTree> item { get; set; }

    public int parentId { get; set; }

}
```

And here's how I use it:

```
var tree = new ItemTree();
tree.id = 0;
tree.text = "sometext";
tree.item = new List<ItemTree>();

foreach (...)
{
    if (tree.item.Count == 0)
    {
      tree.item.Add(new ItemTree
      {
        id = my_id,
        text = my_name,
        item = new List<ItemTree>(),
        parentId = my_par
      });
    }
    else
    {
      tree.item.Where(x => x.id == my_par)
               .Select(x => x.item)
               .First()
               .Add(new ItemTree 
               {
                 id = my_id,
                 text = my_name,
                 item = new List<ItemTree>(),
                 parentId = my_par
               });
    }
}
```

And it crashes in the line with the Where clause.
the reason it crashes is this: the tree has one item who has a list of items, and my query only checks the first item of the tree, not his children.

How to search in the whole depth of the tree and add an item there?

Comment: Is it possible to provide the excect exheption?

Comment: @kostasch. Yes. tree.item.Where(x => x.id == my_par) is null and it throws nullPointerException.

Comment: Can you explain what the line with the `Where` is supposed to be doing? It seems that it tries to insert a grandchild on the first child of the item in a roundabout way?

Comment: @SWeko it needs to insert a child in the tree. The parent of the child should be the item with id == my_par

Comment: So the problem is, find a node in the tree and insert a child?

Comment: I suppose you have check that  tree.item has ItemTree with id == my_par? Imean r you sure that your select have to bring values?

Comment: @SWeko Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @kostasch. Yes I'm sure of that.

Answer (score 4):

It might be convenient to flatten your tree structure into a list.  Some logic will be easier to express if you just have an `IEnumerable<ItemTree>` that contains all the nodes of your tree.  You're not losing any information, since you still have the parent ID on every node.

This is a naturally recursive problem.  Using a recursive lambda, try something like:

```
Func<ItemTree, IEnumerable<ItemTree>> flattener = null;
flattener = t => new[] { t }
                .Concat(t.item == null 
                        ? Enumerable.Empty<ItemTree>()
                        : t.item.SelectMany(child => flattener(child)));
```

Note that when you make a recursive `Func` like this, you must declare the `Func` separately first, and set it to null.

You could also flatten the list using an iterator-block method:

```
public static IEnumerable<ItemTree> Flatten(ItemTree node)
{
    yield return node;
    if (node.item != null)
    {
         foreach(var child in node.item)
             foreach(var descendant in Flatten(child))
                 yield return descendant;
    }
}
```

Either way, once the tree is flattened you can do simple Linq queries over the flattened list to find nodes:

```
flattener(tree).Where(t => t.id == my_id);
```

Then, in order to add to the tree, you can do:

```
var itemOfInterest = flattenedTree.Where(t => t.id == myId).Single();
itemOfInterest.item = itemOfInterest.item ?? new List<ItemTree>();
itemOfInterest.item.Add(myItemToAdd);
```

Where `flattenedTree` was generated using one of our two flattening strategies.

I also want to note that `item` is not a great name for a property that is a list.  Such properties are most often pluralized (`items`).  Also, properties are usually capitalized (`Items`).

Comment: +1. Note: since this is a recursively defined lambda, the declaration line is mandatory. `Func<...> flattener = ...` would not work

Comment: I have answered this too. But your answered remembered me the recursive lambdas! So +1!

Comment: And how would I add the new ItemTree object to this? The one that's in the foreach loop, in the else.

Comment: @petko_stankoski See my updated answer regarding adding nodes to the tree

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectRecursively<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> memberSelector)
{
    foreach (T item in e)
    {
        yield return item;

        IEnumerable<T> inner = memberSelector(item);

        if (inner != null)
            inner.SelectRecursively(memberSelector);
    }
}
```

With usage like:

```
List<ItemTree> tree = GetTree();
List<ItemTree> flattenedTree = tree.SelectRecursively(T => T.Items).ToList();
```

This will start recursive selection (deep traversal), where you can use other **LinQ** features, like [`.Where()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx).

Comment: And how would I add the new ItemTree object to this? The one that's in the foreach loop, in the else.

Comment: @petko_stankoski you just simply get an `ItemTree` and call the `.Items.Add(...)` method on the List.

Answer (score 1):

Solution of @AgentFire from 2013-06-13 at 12:14 must extended to

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectRecursively<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e,
                                                  Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> memberSelector)
{
    foreach (T item in e)
    {
        yield return item;

        IEnumerable<T> inner = memberSelector(item);

        if (inner != null)
        {
            foreach(T innerItem in inner.SelectRecursively(memberSelector))
            {
                yield return innerItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to get the inner items into your result list.

Thanks @AgentFire for this nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`. You should do something like the following instead.

```
var item = tree.item.Where(x => x.id == my_par)
           .Select(x => x.item)
           .FirstOrDefault();

if (item != null)
           .Add(new ItemTree 
           {
             id = my_id,
             text = my_name,
             item = new List<ItemTree>(),
             parentId = my_par
           });
```

Comment: You don't understand. There must be an item in the tree with id == my_par. The problem here is that I don't search in the whole tree.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should add a mehod HasId in your ItemTree
2. The method should implement a recursive search of particulat Id and return answer true or false
3. use (x => x.HasId(my_par))

Comment: Isn't that what I wrote in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to recurse the tree somehow. One solution is to make an iterator for the `ItemTree` object, something like:

```
public class ItemTree
{
  //simple DFS walk of the tree
  public IEnumerable<ItemTree> GetChildren()
  {
     //no items, stop execution
     if ((item == null) || (item.Count == 0))
       yield break;
     foreach (var child in item)
     {
        //return the child first
        yield return child;
        //no way to yield return a collection
        foreach (var grandchild in child.GetChildren())
        {
           yield return grandchild;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Now locating the parent is trivial, something like

```
var parent = tree.GetChilden().First(c => c.id == my_par);
parent.Add(new ItemTree 
{
  id = my_id,
  text = my_name,
  item = new List<ItemTree>(),
  parentId = my_par
});
```

Comment: Ok and how would I add the new ItemTree object to the one GetChildren returns?

Comment: Edited the response to show the actual adding (it's a simple add operation)